# How to configure Opensearch with magento 2.4 in local environment

Tags: magento2.4, search, local, magento2.4.5, opensearch

I need guidance in configuring a Magento 2.4 instance with Opensearch in Local environment.
I am not able to find any proper documentation on the same. Please help.